# Can you perform a case-insensitive string comparison in MSBuild?

Tags: msbuild

I have the following code in my MSBuild project file:

```
<Error Text="Some Text" Condition="'$(StringName)' != 'Test'"/>
```

The string comparison here is case-sensitive, so when `$(StringName)` is something like `'test'`, the condition is not met.

How can I change the condition so that `'test'` also meets the comparison? Is there any case-insensitive comparison function available in MSBuild?

Comment: are you sure its not working? as I recall msbuild condition is case-insensitive.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx

Comment: @ShayErlichmen you recall correctly, they are case-insensitive: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditions?view=vs-2019

Answer (score -12, accepted):

No, there's not.  You'd have to write your own.

Answer (score 46):

Dan Moseley has a detailed view on MSBuild Property Functions here:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/msbuild-property-functions/

For your example you could use something like:

```
<Error Text="Some Text" Condition="'$(StringName.ToUpper())' != 'TEST'"/>
```

Comment: +1 because you do not only quote a link, but rather give a true example. Added a missing closing quote and `Condition` must be uppercase.

Comment: `ToUpperInvariant` would probably be preferable

Comment: Answer from @aaron-jensen is correct, Microsoft documentation clearly states that [MSBuild conditions are already case insensitive](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditions), so there's no need to use any functions here.

Answer (score 27):

MSBuild string comparisons are case-insensitive:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MyProperty>FOOBAR</MyProperty>
</PropertyGroup>

<Message Text="ALL CAPS" Importance="high" Condition="'$(MyProperty)' == 'FOOBAR'" />
<Message Text="all lower" Importance="high" Condition="'$(MyProperty)' == 'foobar'" />
```

will output

```
ALL CAPS
all lower
```

I'm pretty sure something else is going weird in your script.

Comment: Can confirm this observation. This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

Use MSBuild property function with a special parameter to perform a case-insensitive string comparison:

```
<Error Text="Some Text" Condition="!$(StringName.Equals('Test', StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))"/>
```